Failing to understand why the limit is tending to $+\infty$

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that there exists $M>0$ satisfying
$$
\left|f\left(x_1+\cdots+x_n\right)-f\left(x_1\right)-\cdots-f\left(x_n\right)\right| \leq M, \quad \forall x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}
$$
Prove that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.


I have found the following solution:

We argue by contradiction and assume that there exist $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a+b) \neq f(a)+f(b)$. This means that there exists $\varepsilon \neq 0$ such that $f(a+b)=$ $f(a)+f(b)+\varepsilon$. Hence $f(n a+n b)-n f(a+b)=f(n a+n b)-n f(a)-n f(b)-n \varepsilon$. By hypothesis we obtain
$$
|f(n a+n b)-n f(a+b)| \leq M .
$$
Our hypothesis also yields
$$
|f(n a+n b)-n f(a)-n f(b)| \leq M
$$
which implies
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}|f(n a+n b)-n f(a)-n f(b)-n \varepsilon|=+\infty
$$
a contradiction.


In the very last line they say$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}|f(n a+n b)-n f(a)-n f(b)-n \varepsilon|=+\infty
$$ which I dont understand, I do get $-n \varepsilon$ goes to $-\infty$ , but what about $f(an+bn)$? How do gurantee it doesn't to go to $+\infty$ thus balancing it out and the limit being a finite value?

You have\begin{align}|f(na+nb)-nf(a)-nf(b)-n\varepsilon|&=|n\varepsilon-(f(na+nb)-nf(a)-nf(b))|\\&\geqslant|n\varepsilon|-|f(na+nb)-nf(a)-nf(b)|\\&\geqslant n\varepsilon-M\end{align}and therefore, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\varepsilon-M=\infty$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}|f(na+nb)-nf(a)-nf(b)-n\varepsilon|=\infty$.
